# Timeout after around 50 sec

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I am using `express` with `http-proxy` in my application. There's one file upload API which takes more than 2 minutes because I am uploading a file which is to be processed in the backend. when I hit it from browser, I get 504 timeout error after around 50 seconds. I don't know who is causing it. `Express` or `Node` or `http-proxy`.
How do I check it ?
express code :-

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')))

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ secure: false, proxyTimeout : 600000})

app.use('file-upload-api', (req, res) =>  {
proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://someurl' })})
})

app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')))

var server = app.listen(6666, () => console.log('STARTED:', 6666, process.env.NODE_ENV));
```

path is like :-
browser ---> express(node) ---> http-proxy ---> backend(java).

Comment: Please provide more information. What does the endpoint do? some code would be nice

Comment: from UI, I am uploading a file, which is to be processed in the actual backend. 
connection is like this :-
browser ----> node(express) -----> http-proxy -------> Backend(Java).

Comment: check that node is forwarding the upload properly, and setting correct Content-Length (or using correct chunking).  504 is gateway problem, so most likely coming from the proxy.

Comment: @nir_sharma were you able to resolve this? please reply as I am facing same issue.